# I need a probability density function on $\mathbb{R}[0, 1]$ with certain properties.

Tags: probability-distributions, analyticity, means

I'm searching for a very specific probability density function. It needs to have the following 6 properties:

1. Has a support of $\mathbb{R}[0, 1]$, i.e. $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = 1$
2. The pdf must be analytic on the domain $[0,1]$.
3. Is both unimodal and single-peaked.
4. Must have a parameter for the mean which can be set anywhere between $0$ and $1$.
5. Must be monotonically increasing or from $0$ to the mean, then monotonically decreasing from the mean to $1$, i.e. the graph of the function cannot have valleys. It should look like an asymmetric bell-curve.
6. The mean and mode of the pdf are the same.

I've been able to think of probability density functions that satisfy at most 5 of these criteria, but never all 6 at once. For example, a bump function could satisfy all but criterion #2. The beta distribution could satisfy all but #6. The normal distribution could satisfy all but #1.

I need some help. Does such a probability density function exist, and if so, what is it?

Comment: If it's analytic (on $\mathbb R$), it can't be supported in $[0,1]$.  Where exactly do you want it to be analytic?

Comment: Maybe he wants it analytic on a neighborhood of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Not necessarily. The function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)\pi / 2$ is analytic over the real number line, but becomes a pdf on $[0,1]$ when we constrain its domain. However, I just need it analytic over $[0,1]$, primarily because I will likely need to convert it into a taylor series.

Comment: So you want $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ to be the restriction of an analytic function to $[0,1]$?

Comment: In what way do any of these properties matter to you?  A solution which is infinitely differentiable rather than analytic is possible.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, exactly.

Comment: @hardmath I need to be able to convert the function into a taylor series, but if the function is only infinitely differentiable then I won't be able to.

Comment: And why do you need to convert it to a Taylor series?

Comment: @hardmath I'm intending to use this mystery function in some difficult integrals that I'm pretty sure don't possess a closed-form solution unless the function is a polynomial. If I can convert it to a taylor series, then I can evaluate the integral for the first few terms, then approximate the solution in the limit by adding ever more terms. That's the idea, anyway.

Comment: If you want to approximate the function on $[0,1]$ by a Taylor series, you need analyticity on more than just a neighbourhood of $[0,1]$, you need it on a disk containing $[0,1]$.

Comment: But there's more to polynomial approximations than Taylor series.  Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials.  Chebyshev series are often a good choice.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's a good point, but I'm unfortunately very new to using orthogonal polynomials--I've only ever touched the hermite polynomials, and hadn't even heard of Chebyshev series before you mentioned them. I'm still in the stage of my mathematics education where I'm not very comfortable using them. If an analytic version of my desired function doesn't exist, but a continuous version does, then I'd need to go back to the drawing board before I tackle this problem.  =(

Comment: If you're interested in numerical approximations of a function on an interval, rather than near a single point, Chebyshev series are worth looking into.  Much better behaved than Taylor series.